# Script to copy files from one UNC path to another but move the file if older than 24 hours

Tags: powershell, scripting, copy, move, unc

I need to create a scipt that copies all files and folders from \UNCPathA to \UNCPathB but will MOVE any files (retaining folder structure) older than 1 day.

I know how to do this with multiple RoboCopy scripts, but I want to perform both tasks in a single script if possible (perhaps using PowerShell).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done any testing, but I would probably start with something like this:

```
$uncA="\\server\share"
$uncB="\\server\share"
foreach ($item in (Get-ChildItem $uncA)) {
    If ($item.LastWriteTime -lt ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1))) {
        Move-Item $item.FullName $uncB
    } Else {
        Copy-Item $item.FullName $uncB
    }
}
```

`$uncA` and `$uncB` can be UNC or Windows paths (or anything that powershell can understand).

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  I keep getting errors stating "Move-Item : Source and destination path must have identical roots. Move will not work across volumes".  I ran into this before with PowerShell.  There seems to be some limitation with local vs UNC paths?  I've seen other people use "remove-item".

Comment: The help file says "Move-Item will move files between drives that are supported by the same provider, but it will move directories only within the same drive."